# Ubuntu HTML5 App: Change Tab on JS command

Tags: javascript, html, ubuntu, tabs

First Question here, too! Yay! Just moved this from AskUbuntu.
I am just about to finish a little private project for gaining some experience where i try to change the app layout so it works as a normal website (on Jimdo, so it was quite of a challenge first) without much JavaScript required but is fully functional on mobile view.
Since Jimdo serves naturally only the actual site, I had to implement an

```
   if (activeTab.getAttribute('jimdo-target') != null)
     location.href = activeTab.getAttribute('jimdo-target');
```

redirect into the __doSelectTab() function in tabs.js . (In js I took the values from the jimdo menu string to build the TABS menu with this link attribute)
Now everything works fine exept at page load the first tab is selected. I got it to set the .active and .inactive classes right easily, but it is not shifted to the left.
So my next idea is to let it initialize as always and then send a command to change to the current tab.
Do you have any idea how to manage this? I couldn't because of the this.thisandthat element I apparently don't really understand...

Most of you answering have the toolkit and the whole code, but I am listing the select function part of the *tabs.js*:

```
__doSelectTab: function(tabElement, forcedSelection) {
    if ( ! tabElement)
        return;
    if (tabElement.getAttribute("data-role") !== 'tabitem')
        return;
    if (forcedSelection ||
    (Array.prototype.slice.call(tabElement.classList)).indexOf('inactive') > -1) {
        window.clearTimeout(t2);
        activeTab = this._tabs.querySelector('[data-role="tabitem"].active');
        offsetX = this.offsetLeft;
        this._tabs.style['-webkit-transition-duration'] = '.3s';
        this._tabs.style.webkitTransform = 'translate3d(-' + offsetX + 'px,0,0)';
        this.__updateActiveTab(tabElement, activeTab);

        if (activeTab.getAttribute('jimdo-target') != null)
            location.href = activeTab.getAttribute('jimdo-target');

        [].forEach.call(this._tabs.querySelectorAll('[data-role="tabitem"]:not(.active)'), function (e) {
            e.classList.remove('inactive');
        });
        var targetPageId = tabElement.getAttribute('data-page');
        this.activate(targetPageId);
        this.__dispatchTabChangedEvent(targetPageId);
    } else {
        [].forEach.call(this._tabs.querySelectorAll('[data-role="tabitem"]:not(.active)'), function (el) {
            el.classList.toggle('inactive');
        });
        var self = this;
        t2 = window.setTimeout(function () {
            var nonActiveTabs = self._tabs.querySelectorAll('[data-role="tabitem"]:not(.active)');
            [].forEach.call(nonActiveTabs, function (el) {
                el.classList.toggle('inactive');
            });
        }, 3000);
    }
},
```

...and my *app.js* hasn't anything special:

```
var UI = new UbuntuUI();

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() { console.log('device ready') }, true);

$(document).ready(function () {

    recreate_jimdo_nav();

    UI.init();

});
```

Comment: Can you give us a minimum working example of this?

Comment: A _working_ example? I don't know if I understand you right, because, see, I'm from Germany... Meanwhile found a simple workaround I'll post as an answer, however I'd still like to know if there is another way.

Answer (score 0):

So meanwhile found a simple workaround, however I'd still like to know if there is another way. Eventually I noticed the __doSelectTab() function is the one that executes the click, so it does nothing but to show the other tab names when they are hidden first. so I added the global value

```
var jnavinitialized = false;
```

at the beginning of the *tabs.js* and run

```
var t = this;
setTimeout(function(){t.__doSelectTab(t._tabs.querySelector('[data-role="tabitem"].jnav-current'))}, 0);
setTimeout(function(){t.__doSelectTab(t._tabs.querySelector('[data-role="tabitem"].jnav-current'))}, 1);
setTimeout(function(){jnavinitialized = true;}, 10);
```

at the top of the __setupInitialTabVisibility() function. Then I changed the *location.href* command to

```
if (activeTab.getAttribute('jimdo-target') != null && jnavinitialized)
    location.href = activeTab.getAttribute('jimdo-target');
```

And it works. But originally I searched for a way to change the tab on command, not to run the command for selecting twice. So if you know a better or cleaner way, you are welcome!